# Type of element variable

Tags: javascript, variable-types

I am currently reading a book called "The Web Game Developer's Cookbook". In this book, there are many references to creating a new variable and storing or making an element as its value.
For example-

```
var image = document.createElement('img');
```

It says that you can also change many values and attributes of the image like so-

```
image.src = 'image.jpg';
```

So I don't really know whether the variable type is an object, array, or just a reference. So I tried doing this on a jsfiddle.

```
var typeOfImage = typeof image;
typeOfImage = typeOfImage.toString();
console.log(typeOfImage);
```

For some reason, this code does not work. Can someone please help me understand what the data type of an element variable is?
Thanks!

Comment: _"this code does not work"_ If you're getting an error message, please include it in your question to help future searchers.  If you're not getting an error, please explain in what way it's not working and what you're expecting, because it appears to log `object` - note that the `typeof` operator [returns a limited set of values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

Comment: when I run this in jsfiddle it writes `object` to the console.  works as expected. link: https://jsfiddle.net/5erL1euj/

Comment: Sorry- it looks like I had made an error in the code and used typeof as a function, like typeOf(image);

Answer (score 0):

It will be of type `object` and there will be no need to add `toString` because `typeof` returns a string

```
var image = document.createElement('img');
var type = typeof image; // "object"
```

`createElement` returns an DOM element object.